# Modify yaml file with PHP script

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a common.yml file with the following data :

```
main:
  shred:
    viral:
      image1:
        alt: Sunset
        src: 'http://i.imgur.com/nOptw.jpg'
      image2:
        alt: Fernie
        src: 'http://i.imgur.com/yfJaUoX.gif'
```

I am trying to make a php script which edits the 'src' attribute to new image i get from a new json file which i download. The problem is how do i edit the src of these 2 images. I tried to use Symfony Yaml component Dumper but dont know how to use it to update a particular part of my file.

Please help.....

Comment: have you clear the cache after edit it? 
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod      
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev

Comment: @ColourDalnet what does it have to do with updating a yml file. I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you said you have to use the Symfony Yaml component.

For example you can access the "src" data :

```
$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() .'/config/common.yml'));

$srcData = $yaml['main']['schred']['viral']['image1']['src'];
```

Here, your data is accessible = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElkSn.jpg'. Next you can change value and update your file :

```
$yaml['main']['schred']['viral']['image1']['src'] = $yourNewValue;

$new_yaml = Yaml::dump($yaml, 5);

file_put_contents($this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() .'/config/common.yml', $new_yaml);
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks alot Perroin Thibault that solved my problem. but there's a small problem when i do the dump it adds quotes around some other attributes in the file.

Comment: Great ! Have you an example of your problem ? It's strange

Comment: My problem with this is that I need to keep all Comments in the yaml file. Any idea?

Comment: @digitaldonkey just in case anyone ever wanted the same, I wouldn't use comments in the file, instead I always comment the structure using a file like `config.example.yml` and I use it just as a reference, never parse it in the application.

Comment: hello , whaht is it $new_yaml = Yaml::dump($yaml, 5); please ?